# larger imageview for large screen size

Tags: android, android-layout

If I have an image that  I want it to be medium on android medium screen and large on large screens. I know I have to put layouts in 2 different folders:  medium and large layout.
But my question is, should I use one image (say the medium size) and stretch it for the alrge screen by putting min width, min hight and fitscaleXY. 
OR
Should I create 2 images, one for medium sized screen and larger version for large screen?
Thanks

EDIT:

Really no answer yet to this? I am sure this is something people would do all the time. You want the image to be larger on large screens, how do I go about it? I was thinking of specifying width and hight for each screen layout size instead of wrap content.. You agree?

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to make different layout xml files for each screen size, unless they really need a different layout, like how things are organised.

In Android you must specify the sizes in `dp`, and textsizes in `sp`, which is an equivalent to pixels, only they will be scaled automatically based on the screen density.

[Measurement Units](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension).

If you specify some size in dp, it may show up on a large device at for example 300 pixels, and on a smaller device 200 pixels (just an example).

I would Definatedly not hardcode the sizes per screen, since there are a lot of different screens around.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I really appreciate your help in this. My problem is that I am displaying a playing card (saying Jack of spade). Lets assume we are talking medium desnity here all the way. When I run it on normal screen, then the card looks perfect. but when I run it on Xlarge screen ( say tablet) the card looks the same size as before and I am not using the extra space I have. I want to make the card bigger. What do you suggest?